# How do I set the PYTHONPATH on Cygwin?

Tags: python, cygwin, biopython

In the Biopython installation instructions, it says that if Biopython doesn't work I'm supposed to do this:

export PYTHONPATH = $PYTHONPATH':/directory/where/you/put/Biopython'

I tried doing that in Cygwin from the ~ directory using the name of the Biopython directory (or everything of it past the ~ directory), but when I tested it by going into the Python interpreter and typing in

> > From Bio.Seq import Seq

It said the module doesn't exist.

How do I make it so that I don't have to be in the Biopython directory to be able to import Seq?

Answer (score 2):

You can add the directory to your `sys.path` list

```
import sys
biopythondir = '/where/you/put/biopython'
if biopythondir not in sys.path:
  sys.path.append(biopythondir)

# import seq
```

Or, for a more elegant solution than mucking around with environment variables and `sys.path`, see [how to use .pth files to extend sys.path](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html#module-site).

Answer (score 2):

You wrote "(or everything of it past the ~ directory)".  I think you need to use the *full* directory path.  And `~` isn't expanded immediately after a ':', so use `$HOME` instead:

export PYTHONPATH = $PYTHONPATH":$HOME/directory/where/you/put/Biopython"

(Note the use of double rather than single quotes so `$HOME` is expanded.)