# Getting gcloud to work in Cygwin Windows

Tags: python, windows, google-app-engine, cygwin

I am fairly new to programming. I have started app development on google app engine. I am trying to get the Google Cloud SDK to work with Cygwin 32 on Windows. I first ran the curl command to download the Google SDK files. Then I ran the install.py script and installed the SDK, however when calling gcloud in cygwin I receive this message:

```
Ammar Husain@Ammar-Computer:~
$ gcloud
/cygdrive/c/Users/Ammar Husain/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud: line 102: C:\Python27: command not found
```

I have looked everywhere for a solution and have not been able to find one. I examined the gcloud file in the program files and it seems that there may be a problem with the Python Root Directory but I'm not sure. It may also be my Environment Variables.

Someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: Cygwin 32? Do you have a 32bit machine? Otherwise the 64bit Version will be the better choice!

Please have a look here, if you DIDN'T install python via cygwin: [Using python on windows](https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html)

If you DID install it via cygwin: [Set up python on windows](http://www.davidbaumgold.com/tutorials/set-up-python-windows/)

You might also have a look here: [Set the pythonpath on cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199082/how-do-i-set-the-pythonpath-on-cygwin)

In all cases you have to add the python-directory to the PATH-Variable in Windows AND cygwin:

```
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\Path-to-python
echo "PATH=\$PATH:/cygdrive/c/Path-to-python" >> .bash_profile
```

Comment: NOTE: using Cygwin64 will give you:

ERROR: Cygwin 64 bit is not supported by the Google Cloud SDK.  Please use a 32 bit version of Cygwin.

Comment: 64bit version runs just fine, @HidekiAI  It helped me a lot to use folders without spaces or braces

Comment: This did not help. I'm still getting "C:\Python27\python.exe: can't open file '/cygdrive/c/Users...." error when running gcloud in cygwin. I did a hack in gcloud tool. Added following line inside gcloud script: CLOUDSDK_ROOT_DIR="C:\\Users\\$USER\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Cloud SDK\\google-cloud-sdk". Hacky but was the only solution i cloud find for now.

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same problem with Python not understanding the cygwin path. Instead of changing the gcloud script I created a `C:/cygdrive` folder. Then, I opened a windows command prompt and `cd`ed to the new folder. There, I ran `mklink /D c C:\`.

This created a link to the `C:` drive in such a way that Python understands `/cygdrive/c/…`.

Comment: This worked for me as well, thanks!  Just a little note to others: the `mklink` command requires an elevated command prompt (which can be started via the _Run as Administrator_ option from the context menu)

Comment: This was my issue, although it is not exactly what the OP had as a problem. But I had this error:  can't open file '/cygdrive/ ... /google-cloud-sdk/lib/gcloud.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

After installing python 3.8 in my cygwin (with cygwin setup-x86_64.exe), I've used the versioned archive for Linux from

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-versioned-archives

Then, I installed it in my cygwin home directory with this steps:

```
$ tar -xvf google-cloud-sdk-xxx.x.x-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
$ ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh
$ source ~/.bashrc //
```

It worked for me

Comment: What is the  // double slash at the end of that final command?  Could you share a pointer to the docs that explain that?